# Resetting <select> option to previous value

Tags: php, forms, validation

I've created a form with selection boxes that have their data sent by post to the same PHP page that contains it. The selection boxes are checked that their value has been changed from the default by the user by comparing the values in the post. If they are not set, the form redisplays but the selection boxes revert back to their default values.

How can I use the post data to set the boxes back to how the user left them when the form was submitted to avoid the inconvenience to the user?

```
//<form> etc...
 <h2 >Choose your favourite colour</h2>

            <select name="colour">
                <option value="0">Choose a colour:</option>
                <option value="1">Beige</option>
                <option value="2">Sand</option>
                <option value="3">Tan</option>
            </select>
//more form code
```

The post values are checked when the form resubmits:

```
if (isset($_POST['colour']) ) {
    $colour = $_POST['colour'];

    if($colour != 0) {
       //data is all set, redirect
    }else {
        // no value has been set, redisplay form
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Store new value in a session.

Comment: You can set it from PHP, example: `<option value="3" <?php echo isset($_POST['colour']) && $_POST['colour'] == '3' ? 'selected' : '';  ?>>Tan</option>`

Comment: a ternary operator can also be used as outlined ^

Comment: Thanks for your help. I created a function that draws the whole <select> statement, setting the values based on post data. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
/<form> etc...
 <h2 >Choose your favourite colour</h2>

            <select name="colour">
                <option value="0" selected=<?php if($_POST['colour']){$state} else{ echo 'false'} ?> >Choose a colour:</option>
                <option value="1">Beige</option>
                <option value="2">Sand</option>
                <option value="3">Tan</option>
            </select>
//more form code
```

here goes the php code

```
if (isset($_POST['colour']) ) {
    $colour = $_POST['colour'];
    $state = 'false';

    if($colour != 0) {
       //data is all set, redirect
    }else {
        // no value has been set, redisplay form
        $state  = 'true';
    }
}
```